# how to fix Google App Script typeError issue doGet method

Tags: google-apps-script, sms, typeerror

Error ==>
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange')
doGet

Screenshot is attached.
[debugging error point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmah9.png) ..
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HM7f.png)

```
const SHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouvob-GX2H5yfe_BsgNqXtc4xOHjcacjePByn-yWhzc/edit#gid=0";
const SHEET_NAME = "sms_from_Sheet";

const doGet = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  //Logger.log(data);
  if (data != null) {
  Logger.log(sheet.getIndex());
  }
}
```

Comment: From your error message of `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getDataRange')`, I'm worried that in your situation, `sheet` might be null. So, how about checking whether the sheet "sms_from_Sheet" is existing in the Spreadsheet `SHEET_URL`, again? And, if the sheet is existing, how about redeploy your Web Apps as a new version? I'm worried that the latest script might not be reflected in your Web Apps.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouvob-GX2H5yfe_BsgNqXtc4xOHjcacjePByn-yWhzc/edit#gid=0
sheet is existing

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply of `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… sheet is existing`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In my comment, I have also proposed the approach when the sheet is existing. But, from your reply, I cannot know about it. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: sorry also for my poor understanding skill. Actually I couldn't understand your last 2 sentences.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Actually I couldn't understand your last 2 sentences.`, in your showing script, it seems that you are using Web Apps. In this case, when the script is modified, it is required to reflect the latest script to Web Apps. When the latest script is not reflected in the Web Apps, the Web Apps uses old script. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, I proposed reflecting the latest script to your Web Apps and testing it again. In this case, my report might be useful. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)

Comment: I tried this method. Before deploying web apps, there are showing same error. So, previous web app has not deployed perfectly

Comment: Thank you for replying. By the way, now, I saw your Spreadsheet of `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… sheet is existing`. Unfortunately, I cannot find the sheet of `sms_from_Sheet` of `const SHEET_NAME = "sms_from_Sheet";`. But, you say `sheet is existing`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: I didn't get it . My bad.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouvob-GX2H5yfe_BsgNqXtc4xOHjcacjePByn-yWhzc/edit#gid=0

this sheet name is sms_from_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the sheet name that you specified in the code does not match the sheet name you actually have in your spreadsheet. Please, try updating that SHEET_NAME.

```
const SHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouvob-GX2H5yfe_BsgNqXtc4xOHjcacjePByn-yWhzc/edit#gid=0";
const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

const doGet = () => {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
 //Logger.log(data);
 if (data != null) {
  Logger.log(sheet.getIndex());
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Thank you so much. I already waste my 3 hours for that.. Thank you again!